# Display only intersecting elements in CSS

Tags: css, css-mask

Is there a CSS way to display only intersecting elements on the screen?

Take a look at [this layout](https://codepen.io/NeXTs/pen/XWErqJv?editors=1100), it has 4 pseudo-elements, white semi-transparent circles located in the top corners of each square. The circle in the center is a brighter color, because there are 2 semi-transparent circles in that place, they overlap each other.
[image]

The effect I'm trying to achieve is that the side circles are invisible, and only the ones that overlap each other are displayed. But it turned out to be not easy.
[image]

There are `mask`, `mask-composite` CSS properties that [do something like](https://css-tricks.com/mask-compositing-the-crash-course/#aa-css-masking) this, but I can't get them to work.
`mix-blend-mode` didn't help either.

Does anyone have any ideas how this effect could be achieved?

Comment: why you don't remove the before of the first element and the after of the last one?

Comment: this is just a simplified structure for demo. I'm wondering if this can be achieved as a concept

Comment: your *concept* is too broad. If you give your real use case you will get answers otherwise we can only get approximations and guesses

Comment: I understand that I can solve this by changing the layout, but I'm interested in what I asked about in the topic

Comment: what you asked is too broad ... *Is there a CSS way to display only intersecting elements on the screen?* --> no there is no CSS for this BUT if you share a specific use case it can be a "yes"